# mariadb ignoring force index

Tags: mysql, index, performance, mariadb, query-performance

I'm trying to tune a relatively simple query:

```
select bt.col1,bt.col2
from bigtable bt
join smalltable st on bt.smalltable_id = st.smalltable_id
where st.name = 'some name occuring only once in st'
limit 10
```

The number of matches in `bigtable` is relatively small compared to the overall size (< 1%)

Here's the explain plan:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref             | rows     | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | bt    | ALL    | ix_smalltable_id| NULL    | NULL    | NULL            | 22709766 | Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | st    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ix_name | PRIMARY | 2       | bt.smalltable_id|        1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-------------+
```

Somehow, even though it would be easier to pickup the index, it doesn't.

I then tried to force the index:

```
select bt.col1,bt.col2
from bigtable bt force index (ix_smalltable_id)
join smalltable st on bt.smalltable_id = st.smalltable_id
where st.name = 'some name occuring only once in st'
limit 10
```

But the query plan and query time is the same. It doesn't want to use the index.

I tried doing where bt.smalltable_id in (select ...), but same query plan and time.

But if I fetch the `smalltable_id` first, and then embed it in the select, it's much faster.

**The question**

Can I force the index by enabling some flags? Is this a limitation of the query engine?

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `smalltable` (
  `smalltable_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`smalltable_id`),
  KEY `ix_name` (`name`(10))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5698 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `bigtable` (
  `bigtable_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `smalltable_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bigtable_id`),
  KEY `ix_smalltable_id` (`smalltable_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23167374 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Can you add the tables' structure (with `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`)?

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: This was a very refreshing question. +1 !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is the "partial" index:

```
CREATE TABLE `smalltable` (
  ...
  KEY `ix_name` (`name`(10))
)
```

Try running the query after adding an index on the full length of the column:

```
ALTER TABLE smalltable
    DROP INDEX ix_name
  , ADD INDEX ix_name_full (name) ;
```

Comment: that partial index is what I was eyeballing too. +1

Comment: I hate those types of indexes. +1 for the good eye.

Comment: I just noticed that since ix_name is not unique, the index will only be used when there is only one row in `smalltable`.

Comment: The index will be used whether it is unique or not. If the `name` column has no two identical values, then it would be better to define the index as `UNIQUE`.

Comment: The ix_name will be, but not the bigtable.ix_smalltable_id. I have a few case where 25 entries were created in smalltable with identical name, and if you use those, you end up with full table scan. Writing a deduplicating job now.

Comment: which version of MariaDB do you use?

Answer (score 2):

What does `STRAIGHT_JOIN` give you if you rewrite the query:

```
SELECT bt.col1,bt.col2
FROM smalltable st
STRAIGHT_JOIN bigtable bt ON bt.smalltable_id = st.smalltable_id
WHERE st.name = 'some name occuring only once in st'
LIMIT 10
```

I'm mostly curious to see if that is a faster plan, or if MySQL optimizer is  'right' to read in the bigtable rows first.

To further answer the question about MariaDB 'ignoring' force index, the problem is there is nothing for it to use when you do `FORCE INDEX (ix_smalltable_id)` because it will have to do a full table scan of `bigtable` anyway.

You might try `FORCE INDEX (ix_name)` (especially in conjunction with [changing the partial index to a full index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30311/180) as ypercube suggests) to see if that helps, but if it does anything it will probably be the same as the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` refactor.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things you can do

## USE A BETTER INDEX

Instead of forcing an index on `bigtable`, make the following index on `smalltable`

```
ALTER TABLE smalltable ADD INDEX name_smalltable_id_ndx (name,smalltable_id);
```

Since you posted the table structures, I can now see that `smalltable` is InnoDB. In light of this,  there is no need for any additional index. You do have a name index `ix_name`.

## REFACTOR THE QUERY

Here is your original query

```
select bt.col1,bt.col2
from bigtable bt
join smalltable st on bt.smalltable_id = st.smalltable_id
where st.name = 'some name occuring only once in st'
limit 10
```

Try taking advantage of the `ix_name` index and running `limit 10` before doing the join

```
select bt.col1,bt.col2
from 
(
    select b.bigtable_id 
    from bigtable b
    join smalltable s on b.smalltable_id = s.smalltable_id
    where s.name = 'some name occuring only once in st'
    limit 10
) st
join bigtable bt on st.bigtable_id = bt.bigtable_id;
```

I know this is not the same as the original. I don't expect the EXPLAIN plans to be the same.

Please look at the original query and the refactor and compare:

- Both execute a WHERE clause on `smalltable`
- Both have no WHERE clause on `bigtable`

  - That's the reason the `ix_smalltable_id` index is not used
  - Query Optimizer saw no `WHERE` clause and opted for full table scan as expected
- Both want to display 10 rows

  - Original query picks 10 rows after the join
  - Refactored query picks 10 keys from `smalltable` before join

The one slight advantage of the refactored query is the use of the `ix_name` index. Since secondary key in InnoDB has the primary key attached, it can serve to help the subquery in the refactored query.

In some respects, a refactored query could produce a far worse EXPLAIN plan. In this particular case, I dared to suggest refactoring because of the `limit 10`. I actually tested this scenario in StackOverflow back on `May 16, 2011` :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023217/491757 . In that post, the query had a worse EXPLAIN PLAN but proved faster over time with more data.

### Thanks to @ypercube for refactoring my refactored query !!!

Comment: Sorry but your refactoring is not equivalent to the original query.

Comment: already an index on smalltable_id, it's the primary key

Comment: OK since the `smalltable` is InnoDB and you have `ix_name`, no need for an additional index.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: Consider this: all rows of `bigtable` having the same `smalltable_id`. Then your query may return all of them (22M rows) while the original will never return more than 10.

Comment: @ypercube OK I think I am starting to get it. In that respect the queries are not same. In fact, I think if the `limit 10` were applied on `bigtable` before the join, then the query would be the same. What do you think ??? (Let me tweek the refactor)

Comment: I will edit your answer. You can rollback if you disagree.

Comment: @ypercube OK standing by...

Comment: @ypercube That's less baggage for the JOIN. Pretty neat. I would +1 but this is my answer. Please repost it as yours.

Comment: No, I noticed something else, just now :)

Comment: @ypercube I was going to remove my answer if you were going to use the refactor. If you have a different answer altogether, I'd like to see it.